# Swagger UI endpoint doesn't return UTF-8 encoded response using ABP.IO

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using abp framework as in http://www.abp.io

Now, executing this endpoint /api/abp/application-configuration using Swagger UI returns a json results see snippet below

Not sure why the results isn't UTF-8 encoded, I am expecting Mâle but got M�le

your help is appreciated

[image]

Comment: [Does this help?](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5311#issuecomment-495324285)

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

1. Open the json file ie fr.json
2. Change the encoding to UTF-8 , you can use VS or Notepad++
3. Save the file
4. reopen the file to ensure change is done